# Issue with proximity search, with wildcard terms inside specified elements in MarkLogic

Tags: search, marklogic

We are using MarkLogic 7.0-4. We are facing a problem with proximity search, with wildcard terms inside specified elements.

The query looks like following:

```
cts:near-query(
  (
    cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("abstract"), "microf*)", 
      ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive",
       "whitespace-sensitive","unstemmed","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1),
    cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("abstract"), "transplant*)",
      ("case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive",
       "whitespace-sensitive","unstemmed","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1)
  ), 2, (), 1)
```

We are running *unfiltered*. It's supposed to return documents having the wildcard terms within specified elements. Although currently no document matches the query, a document is being returned. Apparently the document is a match because it has an element, not among the specified ones, which has the wildcard terms within the given distance.

Among the related index settings we have the following one enabled:

*element word positions,
  fast element phrase searches,
  three character searches,
  three character word positions,
  fast element character searches,
  fast element word searches,
  trailing wildcard searches,
  trailing wildcard word positions,
  fast element trailing wildcard searches*

Sample data to reproduce:

```
xdmp:document-insert(
  '/questions/33865927-1.xml',
  <root>
    <abstract>microfoo blah blah blah blah transplantbar</abstract>
  </root>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the `word positions` index and the false positive went away.

You have `element word positions` turned on. I suspect that only stores where terms are related to the containing element, rather than location in the document overall (don't quote me on that). For this query, even when I turned off `element word positions` I got the right answer, as long as `word positions` was on.